# Responsive menu script only seems to work 2 levels deep

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm using Matt Kersley responsive menu script but it only seems to work 2 levels deep. Any menu links which are nested more that 2 unordered lists deep will not display at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/fVAVN/  (resize the browser window to see the responsive functionality)

Any clues on what's preventing the level 3 links from displaying in the mobile drop-down?

Comment: Please choose a descriptive title for your question.

Answer (score 0):

After having a look over the plugin code, there is no indication that it is designed to go deeper that 2 levels. There's no recursion to generate unlimited nesting levels inside the select, just for the immediate children `li` of the main list (in the `createSelect()` function) and any second level children (in the `createOptionGroup()` function).

The actual demo from his site which has lists 3 levels deep only shows 2 levels inside the select:
http://mattkersley.com/demos/responsive_menu/

You might want to report this issue on the plugins GitHub issue tracker:
https://github.com/mattkersley/Responsive-Menu/issues

Comment: thanks for your reply. i did indeed see that his own demo only works 2 levels deep. I just though (I'm not that good at JS/JQuery myself) there was an "easyfix"-solution/extend functionality before I bother the author =)